# Oracle PL/SQL code to concatenate not null string values with a delimiter

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have five strings str1 str2 str3 str4 str5. These strings may or may not be null. How can I write code to concatenate only the the strings that are not null with a delimiter ',' ?

Eg 1 : only str1 and str3 are not null
str1 - 'A'
str3 - 'B'
Desired Output: A/B

Eg 2 : only str2 is not null
str2 - 'A'
Desired Output: A

Comment: delimiter `,` or `/` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` expression to concatenate only the non-`NULL` values with leading delimiters and then trim the initial delimiter:

```sql
DECLARE
  str1 VARCHAR2(1) := 'A';
  str2 VARCHAR2(1) := 'B';
  str3 VARCHAR2(1) := NULL;
  str4 VARCHAR2(1) := 'D';
  str5 VARCHAR2(1) := NULL;
  combined VARCHAR2(9);
BEGIN
  combined := SUBSTR(
                   CASE WHEN str1 IS NOT NULL THEN ','||str1 END
                || CASE WHEN str2 IS NOT NULL THEN ','||str2 END
                || CASE WHEN str3 IS NOT NULL THEN ','||str3 END
                || CASE WHEN str4 IS NOT NULL THEN ','||str4 END
                || CASE WHEN str5 IS NOT NULL THEN ','||str5 END,
                2
             );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(combined);
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

```
A,B,D
```

You could also use the `NVL2` function instead of a `CASE` expression.

---

If you want to use SQL (rather than PL/SQL, which you tagged the question with) then:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(
            CASE WHEN str1 IS NOT NULL THEN ','||str1 END
         || CASE WHEN str2 IS NOT NULL THEN ','||str2 END
         || CASE WHEN str3 IS NOT NULL THEN ','||str3 END
         || CASE WHEN str4 IS NOT NULL THEN ','||str4 END
         || CASE WHEN str5 IS NOT NULL THEN ','||str5 END,
         2
       ) AS combined
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name( str1, str2, str3, str4, str5) AS
  SELECT 'A', 'B', NULL, 'D', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, NULL, 'C', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| COMBINED |
| --- |
| A,B,D |
| C |
| A,B,C,D,E |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/u6v_mgjI)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to minimize the amount of copy-paste code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc (in_string IN varchar2)
  RETURN varchar2
AS
BEGIN
  IF in_string IS NOT NULL
  THEN
    RETURN in_string||',';
  ELSE
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
END;
```

Then use it either in SQL or in PL/SQL:

```
SELECT RTRIM(myfunc(str1)||myfunc(str2)||myfunc(str3)||myfunc(str4)||myfunc(str5),',')
  FROM ...
```

or

```
DECLARE
  concat_string varchar2(1000);
BEGIN
  concat_string := RTRIM(myfunc(str1)||myfunc(str2)||myfunc(str3)||myfunc(str4)||myfunc(str5),',');
END;
```

Comment: If the last value includes a trailing comma then using `RTRIM` will remove part of the value as well as the delimiter.

Comment: @MT0, very astute as always, but of course if the strings in question can contain commas, OP shouldn't be choosing commas as a delimiter. It would be bad programming to choose a delimiter character that could appear in the items being delimited.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `DECODE` [reference here](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-comparison-functions/oracle-decode/)

```sql
-- SETUP THE TEST
create table X (a nvarchar2(10), b nvarchar2(10), c nvarchar2(10));
 
insert into X values ('a', null, 'c');
insert into X values (null, null, 'c');
insert into X values ('a', 'b', 'c');
insert into X values ('a', 'b', null);


-- RUN
select rtrim(
    DECODE(a, null, '', a || ',') ||
    DECODE(b, null, '', b || ',') ||
    DECODE(c, null, '', c || ','), ',') as result
from X;
```

| RESULT |
| --- |
| a,c |
| c |
| a,b,c |
| a,b |

**Update:** I was noted that above code will trim not only one trailing comma but also all trailing commas as part of the value. While I can argue that if this is a comma delimited file, the string value containing commas would be in the quotes. But this is not a comma delimited file in any case. I don't see how this question "has in mind" commas in data. Still, here is improved use of `DECODE` which will solve this issue

```sql
with
  T as (SELECT DECODE(a, null, '', a || ',') ||
               DECODE(b, null, '', b || ',') ||
               DECODE(c, null, '', c || ',') as col1 from X)
select substr(col1, 0, length(col1) - 1) as result from T
```

Comment: If the last value includes a trailing comma then using `RTRIM` will remove part of the value as well as the delimiter.

Comment: @MT0 Please see the improved answer. Thanks for pointing out,.